# Adding list of items to an objects list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to add the **attractions** list items to the objects **tripAttractions** list but it doesn't seem like its working. How do I add these items correctly?

```
 class Trip {
          String image;
          String name;
          String location;
          List<Attraction> tripAttractions = [];

          Trip({this.image , this.name, this.location, this.tripAttractions});
        }

    final List<Trip> tripList = [
        Trip(image: 'test image', name: 'NY Trip', location: 'NY Address', tripAttractions: attractions)];

    List<Attraction> attractions = [
        Attraction('name', 'address', 'imageURL')];
```

[image: Code output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your tripAttractions is of the type List where Attraction is a class, you'll have to access variables by using the object, for example

You will have to iterate through the tripAttraction list and access the data as follows,

```
tripAttractions[0].name
tripAttractions[0].address
tripAttractions[0].imageURL
```

Comment: Wow so simple yet I was going crazy trying to figure this out lol. Thanks!